# how to save a zommable picture in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to save a curve picture.

matplotlib `plt.show()` is great.

since i can zomm in to see the small part of the picture

but once a savefig, it will be saved in a png, which is not able to zoom in.

is there any method i can get a zoomable picture saved?

Comment: You mean you want to be able to save an image that can be zoomed later? Or do you want to save a section of your curve zoomed in?

Comment: @JasonChia image that can be zoomed later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot save interactive plots with matplotlib. You might want to check out something like [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) to generate interactive HTML plots.